# Getting Segmentation fault when using qsort for sorting array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, qsort

I'm trying to sort an array of strings that I initialized like this.

```
char que[100][100];
```

This is my comparison function

```
int compfunc(const void * a, const void * b){
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

and this is the call to qsort that i am making

```
qsort(que, size, sizeof(char *), compfunc);
```

size is the correct the number of elements that I have in the array.
But I am getting a segmentation fault when I try and run the code.
Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong size to `qsort`.

```
qsort(que, size, sizeof(char *), compfunc);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It should be:

```
qsort(que, size, sizeof(que[0]), compfunc);
```

Remember that the numerical difference between `&q[0]` and `&q[1]` is `100`, which is the same as `sizeof(q[0])`.

Also, to be pedantic, the pointer type in `compfun` needs to be `char (*)[100]`, not `char**`. After all, `q` decays to a pointer of type `char (*)[100]`.

```
int compfunc(const void * a, const void * b){
    const char (*ia)[100] = (const char (*)[100])a;
    const char (*ib)[100] = (const char (*)[100])b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

even though what you have should work.

Answer (score 2):

The seg fault is due to the *compfunc* function

```
int compfunc(const void * a, const void * b){
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}
```

no need of extra (and wrong) casting that causes the derefence of a non-pointer and the segmentation fault (undefined behavior actually)

```
int compfunc(const void * a, const void * b){
    return strcmp(a, b);
}
```

gives you what you need.

Also, as R Sahu mentioned, the size of an element given to *qsort* is also wrong, it should be the size of one of the elements you want to be compared (and sorted), ie the size of `que[0]` for instance, or `*que`

```
qsort(que, size, sizeof(*que), compfunc);
```